# Does Nautilus remote mounting use SSHFS?

Tags: mount, nautilus, files

Does Nautilus' (Ubuntu 16.x or 17.x) remote file system mounting using SSHFS or something else?

**Note to Moderators:** For keyword purposes, I've tagged this with "Files" because, although the application being discussed is technically called Nautilus, this is not stated basically anywhere in the Ubuntu GUI - it's always referred to as "Files" instead. So, newbies like myself searched using that keyword.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can press <kbd>Ctrl+L</kbd> and enter SSH address here in Nautilus/Files (and Caja) - for example:

```
sftp://localhost/
```

This will create GVFS-mountpoint in `/run/user/$UID/gvfs/` (in this example `/run/user/$UID/gvfs/sftp:host=localhost`):

```
$ mount | grep gvfs
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
```

So Nautilus/Files (and Caja) uses GVFS.

---

If you want you can mount folder via SSHFS:

```
sudo apt-get install sshfs
mkdir ~/sshfs
sshfs user@host.local:/ ~/sshfs
```

Then Nautilus/Files (and Caja) will show it in *Devices* section.

Nautilus can't unmount it by Unmount because of [bug 254171](https://bugs.launchpad.net/debian/+source/nautilus/+bug/254171).
One can use `sudo fusermount -u ~/sshfs` for this purpose.

Comment: Where can I read about the syntax for the SFTP command? When I execute sftp://user@ip 'no such file or directory'. Thank you. This was really informative.

Comment: You should write this in Nautilus address bar (accessed by `<Ctrl+L>`, not in command line (not in terminal). Or use *Connect to server*.

Comment: Oh, I see I misunderstood. So I'm aware that's the syntax to connect to a server via Nautilus. And at least in 17.10 it automatically mounts it. So I'm not clear what `mount | grep gvfs` is about. Is that just to see where and how it was mounted from the command line?

Comment: "Is that just to see where and how it was mounted from the command line" - yes. `mount | grep gvf` is a test to show where SFTP-share was mounted.