# FTP via Nautilus and via command line

Tags: ftp, sftp

If I try and access my FTP server via the command line using `(sudo) sftp 192.168.1.x/home/directory` the terminal returns

> sftp: 192.168.1.x/home/directory: Name or service not known

But if I enter `sftp://192.168.1.x/home/directory` into Nautilus the directory is accessible.

Why am I not able to access the ftp server with the command line?

I have been having problems with FTP and backing up my system since yesterday so I might be missing something obvious by now. Sorry if that is the case.

Comment: Are you sure that you completely understand the terminology? SFTP is SSH-ed FTP. FTP is insecure, FTPS is FTP with SSL security. What server do you use? OpenSSH or VsftpD?

Comment: I use openSSH to connect to my server via ssh and also use vsftp. My problems started when I upgraded my server to from 16.04 to 18.04 and my Deja Dup GUI could no longer backup my laptop. I had to alter the storage target to `sftp://192.168.1.x/home/directory` to get it to work. Previously it was `ftp://directory@192.168.1.x/` for many years. I am trying to figure out what has happened for this long-term solution to stop working.

Comment: Sounds interesting. I use `sshfs` to mount SFTP to the mount-point (see example in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1025031/66509)). It is fast and reliable. Or Nautilus/Caja to mount sftp for copying/moving one or two  files. I have never used Deja Dup. I use [FreeFileSync](https://askubuntu.com/a/1040956/66509) for periodical but manual backups.

Comment: I have used Deja Dup for years now and am very happy with it. I found the command `sftp://192.168.1.x/home/directory` by connecting via Nautilus and so everything is working again now. But I am interested in what exactly has changed and it is so long ago that I set up the OpenSSH, vsftp anf other servers on my server machine that I have forgotten 90% of how I did it ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally discovered why the SFTP wasn't working in the command line, it was because somehow during the upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04 the bash shell had been removed from the user "directory".  I found this out by looking at `/etc/passwd` and noticed that the entry for "directory" had `/usr/bin/nologin` next to it. I entered the following command to fiy the problem.

> sudo usermod --shell /bin/bash directory

Answer (score 1):

According to [`man sftp`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/sftp.1.html):

```
 sftp [user@]host[:file ...]
```

So you need a colon `:` between the server name and path.

```
sftp 192.168.1.x:/home/directory
```

Or better still, use a tilde `~` for the home directory!

```
sftp 192.168.1.x:~/
```

Comment: Thanks but even adding a colon didn't change the result. Still the same warning.